# What's the correct direction of a date embedded in arabic text?

Tags: date, arabic, bidi

The question is quiet simple: I've got an arabic text with an US formated Date in it. What is the correct display order of this date? Is it(for instance) 01/10/2009 or 2009/10/1?

The bidi algorithm recognizes the numbers an slashes as neutral and orders them in the same direction like the surrounding text. So the date should be backwards but that's not what any browser does. On the other hand, i can't find any rule in the unicode bidi algorithm which excludes date patterns. So, what is correct here and (especially) why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without going deep in the technical details

I can tell that 01/10/2009 is the correct one and some times it's 10/01/2009
but it's never 2009/10/1